# OpenStreetMap error when configuring my own server

Tags: linux, postgresql, openstreetmap

I'm building my own tile server for OpenStreeMap following [this guide](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server/)

But when I do `renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf`, it says there is a syntax problem.

```
osmswing@SRV-OPENSTREETMAP:/home/osmtileserver$ renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
renderd[19977]: Rendering daemon started
renderd[19977]: Initiating reqyest_queue
iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (7):
-> ;[renderd01]
iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (14):
-> ;[renderd02]
iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (33):
-> ;** config options used by mod_tile, but not renderd **
iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (44):
-> ;[style2]
iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (51):
-> ;** config options used by mod_tile, but not renderd **
renderd[19977]: Parsing section renderd
renderd[19977]: Parsing render section 0
renderd[19977]: Parsing section mapnik
renderd[19977]: Parsing section default
renderd[19977]: config renderd: unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[19977]: config renderd: num_threads=4
renderd[19977]: config renderd: num_slaves=0
renderd[19977]: config renderd: tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[19977]: config renderd: stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[19977]: config mapnik:  plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
renderd[19977]: config mapnik:  font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
renderd[19977]: config mapnik:  font_dir_recurse=1
renderd[19977]: config renderd(0): Active
renderd[19977]: config renderd(0): unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[19977]: config renderd(0): num_threads=4
renderd[19977]: config renderd(0): tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[19977]: config renderd(0): stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[19977]: config map 0:   name(default) file(/home/osmswing/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml) uri(/osm_tiles/) htcp() host(localhost)
renderd[19977]: Initialising unix server socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[19977]: Created server socket 4
renderd[19977]: Renderd is using mapnik version 2.0.3
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
renderd[19977]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
Running in foreground mode...
renderd[19977]: Starting stats thread
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[19977]: Loading parameterization function for 
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[19977]: Loading parameterization function for 
renderd[19977]: Loading parameterization function for 
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[19977]: Loading parameterization function for 
Postgis Plugin: SRID warning, using srid=-1
renderd[19977]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou prÃ¨s de Â« 1.1827477021045268e-316 Â»
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 1.1827477021045268e-316 LIMIT 0
                      ^
Full sql was: 'SELECT * FROM 1.1827477021045268e-316 LIMIT 0'
 (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/home/osmswing/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
Postgis Plugin: SRID warning, using srid=-1
Postgis Plugin: SRID warning, using srid=-1
renderd[19977]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou prÃ¨s de Â« 6.9038307131763969e-310 Â»
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 6.9038307131763969e-310 LIMIT 0
                      ^
Full sql was: 'SELECT * FROM 6.9038307131763969e-310 LIMIT 0'
 (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/home/osmswing/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
renderd[19977]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou prÃ¨s de Â« 6.903824082086584e-310 Â»
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 6.903824082086584e-310 LIMIT 0
                      ^
Full sql was: 'SELECT * FROM 6.903824082086584e-310 LIMIT 0'
 (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/home/osmswing/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
Postgis Plugin: SRID warning, using srid=-1
renderd[19977]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou prÃ¨s de Â« 6.9038273972125228e-310 Â»
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 6.9038273972125228e-310 LIMIT 0
                      ^
Full sql was: 'SELECT * FROM 6.9038273972125228e-310 LIMIT 0'
 (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/home/osmswing/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
```

Could you please tell me why? I can't find a similar problem...

Comment: It is difficult to help you without knowing the content of those files. It would be the best to ask at the *#osm* IRC channel in the OFTC network. And please post the solution here afterwards.

Comment: In fact, I think it is a problem of the operating systems. I have installed OSM on Debian on following a tuto written for Ubuntu. There are several packages that could not be found. And I finally found a tuto for Debian wheezy in French. http://adrien.caillot.free.fr/?p=5362